# Angular4 multiple modules issue

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have an app which has multiple views like navigation and pages. So I added a layout module and imported that module to the main module & now trying to use layout modules navigation component in app component. So this should show navigation.html content but its coming as blank. It's not giving any error as well. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Well below is my code that will give the proper picture:
here is app.model.ts

```
    

    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { LayoutsModule } from './layouts/index';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LayoutsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],   
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

and here is LayoutsModule

```
   

    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        NavigationComponent
      ],
      exports: [

      ],
      imports: [

      ],
      providers: [

      ]
    })
    export class LayoutsModule {}
```

and my app.component.html

```
 

    <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should export `NavigationComponent` from your `LayoutsModule` so that it can usable out `LayoutsModule`. Basically whatever you want to exposed to be used by another module/ system inside Angular, you have to put those `component`/`directive`/`pipe` inside `exports` metadata options of `NgModule` or rather it could have been loaded via `route` segment from Angular Router.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavigationComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      NavigationComponent
  ],
  imports: [],
  providers: []
})
export class LayoutsModule {}
```

Not sure why you didn't get an error. It should've thrown an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the component(s) in your `LayoutModule` that you want to make available to other modules:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavigationComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    NavigationComponent,
  ],
  imports: [

  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class LayoutsModule {}
```

More information on sharing modules: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules